# react-native-mail through mail App (IOS) is sending email only if logged with gmail account

Tags: html, react-native, email

I have the following problem when to use the react-native-mail library in my IOS app:

- The lib only works when I'm logged into the mail app through Gmail account, it doesn't work with Icloud or others.
- Sometimes when logged with gmail, the confirmation message is displayed, but the email doesn't reach the recipient.
- Is it the same problem as the following link: https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/issues/195

This library handle also HTML in the email body, is there an alternative solution for sending email with HTML or attachment (PDF) in the body?